# No cout printing in pthread starting function

Tags: pthreads, cout

i'm new here and noob with pthread programming.
My problem is in a C++ class, that i'm trying to create to encapsulate a thread.
Reading around i'd seen that when i create a pthread, i need to pass a C function to pthread_create that it runs on startup... So, when the pthread runs that function it doesn't cout the message on stdout!

But it's better if you see the code:
(obviously it's copy and pasted from an internet tutorial ^^)

```
void *runAtStart( void *threadid)
{

    long tid;
   tid = (long)threadid;

   printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n", tid);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}


Thread::Thread() {
    pthread_t threads[1];
   int rc;
   long t;
   for(t=0; t<1; t++){
      printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
      rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, runAtStart, (void *)t);
      if (rc){
         printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
        // exit(-1);
      }
   }
}
```

in the main i call this as:

```
int main()
{
    Thread *th=new Thread();
    return 0;
}
```

the output generated is:

```
In main: creating thread 0
```

i hope that someone has understood!
sorry for my English! :)
Inzirio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program runs fine. The problem you're seeing is that your main() function returns before your thread can actually run, and this causes your program to exit.

A simple way to prove this is to add `sleep(5);` in `main()`, prior to your return call. A better way is to find a manner to cause main() to wait until all of its threads have completed before it returns. One reasonable manner to do that is to add a destructor to your Thread class that performs a pthread_join, and be sure you actually call the destructor: `delete th;`